# Unsubscribed contact delete in marketing cloud - anything to keep in mind?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

We have million contacts that are unsubscribed and are billable. We only send emails. No PUSH/SMS.. We want to explore the option of deleting them from marketing cloud and keep a record elsewhere. We know it is not recommended by marketing cloud. But other than that, what other problems we might face during and after the deletion? I guess the question is, should we delete it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only "delete" is a GDPR (right to be forgotten) delete. So, when you mess this up, and most do, those contacts are gone-gone. There's no undo. Your application, if it's using the push SDK, will cease all communication with the server.

My recommendation is that you be very, very careful about the contacts that end up in your list to delete or you're going to delete contacts you care about and you'll deactivate the SDK in your application.

If you are referring to something other than the push channel, then I'll defer to the bot's suggestion about editing your question with more detail :)

Comment: We don't have push SDK. We are using MC for sending only email. We have a lot of journey and triggered emails as well as adhoc emails that we send. Over the years, we gathered a lot of unsubscribes and marketing cloud bills us for the unsub. We are not sure if deleting them would cause any issue.  MC says they keep the contacts held and are billable because we might need to send transactional email to the unsub contacts.

Comment: Right on. I'm leaving my answer as it might help someone else.